# order of upper and lower indices in a second order tensor

Tags: tensors

In his book on "General Relativity" Woodhouse mentions on page 27 that,

> ...One must be careful to keep track of the order of the upper and lower indices because ${T^a}_b$ and ${T_b}^a$ are generally distinct.

I do not understand this since I thought that the purpose of a raised or lowered index is to indicate the transformation properties of each index and since both ${T^a}_b$ and ${T_b}^a$ are tensors of type (1,1) they are indistinguishable. I am obviously missing something ... Can someone expand on this comment by Woodhouse?

Comment: For tensors with three+ indices there are oftentimes nice properties about switching around the ordering (which requires knowing the original order of the indices). Look at the Reimann Curvature Tensor, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the catch: if $T$ is a tensor of type $(0,2)$, then one may define *two* type $(1,1)$ tensors corresponding to $T$ under the metric. If we call them $T_1$ and $T_2$, they are all related by $$T(v,w) = \langle T_1(v), w\rangle = \langle v,T_2(w)\rangle.$$The problem is that $T_1 =T_2$ happens if and only if $T$ is symmetric. However, it will still be true that ${\rm tr}(T_1) = {\rm tr}(T_2)$. This illustrates that while $T^a_{~~~b} \neq T_b^{~~~a}$ in general, we do have $T^a_{~~a}=T_a^{~a}$ (summation over $a$).

Comment: Apologies but I do not understand this. In tensor ${T^a}_b$, $a$ is the contravariant index and $b$ is the covariant index. In tensor ${T_b}^a$ the same is true. Whatever ${T^1}_2$ is, it is identical to ${T_2}^1$ for $a=1,b=2$ and this is independent of the properties of $T$. So if two tensors have the same transformation properties and the same elements aren't they exactly the same?

Comment: "Whatever $T^1_{~~~2}$ is, it is identical to $T_2^{~~~1}$..." Again, no! By definition, $T^a_{~~~b} = g^{ac}T_{cb}$ and $T_{b}^{~~~a} = g^{ac}T_{bc}$. Try it with any non-symmetric $T$ and you'll see the difference.

Comment: OK ... maybe I finally got it but please bear with me. If $g^{ac}=\delta^{ac}$ then using your equations, ${T^a}_b=\delta^{ac}T_{cb}$ and ${T_b}^a=\delta^{ac}T_{bc}$. So even under a Euclidean metric ${T^a}_b \neq {T_b}^a$?!?

Comment: Yes, even under an Euclidean metric! Symmetry of $T$ is what matters. In the answer above, $T_2$ is the adjoint of $T_1$. Relative to an orthonormal basis, the matrix representing the adjoint of an operator is the transpose of the matrix representing the original operator. And why do we get equality when $b=a$ and we sum over it? Because the trace of $A^\top$ equals the trace of $A$, for any square matrix $A$.

Comment: If I may, an addendum on the same subject: would it be right (for any second order tensor, not just a symmetric one) to write ${T^a}_b={T_a}^b$? This question is not coming out of the blue! If we write the product of two matrices $AB=C$ as ${A^i}_k {B^k}_j = {C^i}_j$ we know from linear algebra that $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$. Using index notation this is only possible if we can write ${B_k}^j{A_i}^k={C_i}^j$. But this is a heuristic and there must be a proof using the metric tensor...